# Input not being detected in scene Unity. Works when starting the game from that scene; does not work otherwise

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a game where the start screen is level 0, the actual playable levels are levels 1-4, and the lose screen is level 5. My issue is with the lose screen. Here's my code:

```
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && (CurrentLevel == 0)){
        CurrentLevel = 1;
        Application.LoadLevel (CurrentLevel);
    }

    if (CharacterMovement.Score == 10) {
        CurrentLevel = 2;
        CharacterMovement.Score = 11;
        Application.LoadLevel (CurrentLevel);

    }

    if (CharacterMovement.Lives == 0) {
        isLost = true;
        Debug.Log ("is now true");
        CurrentLevel = 5;
        Debug.Log ("current level is set to 5");
        Application.LoadLevel (CurrentLevel);
    }

    if (CurrentLevel == 5) {
        Debug.Log ("this is level 5");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)) {
            Debug.Log ("tab is pressed");

        }
    }
}
```

When I lose all of my lives I'm properly sent to the lose screen, and I receive the following logs from `Debug.Log`: "is now true", "current level is set to 5", and "this is level 5." However, when I press tab on the lose screen, I never receive the log "Tab is pressed". This is important because I want to be able to reset the game to the start screen when the key is pressed.

The weird thing is that if I press play from the lose screen in the Unity editor and hit tab, it works perfectly. But if I play through again and lose all my lives and try to hit tab, it doesn't work again.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you lose the game and load scene 5, Your `Lives` still are zero, so `CharacterMovement.Lives == 0` will be true and you just load scene 5 repeatedly. If you look at your console I guess there is a lot of `this is level 5` in that. You have to handle this situation.

You can do something like this:

```
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) && (CurrentLevel == 0)){
        CurrentLevel = 1;
        Application.LoadLevel (CurrentLevel);
    }

    if (CharacterMovement.Score == 10) {
        CurrentLevel = 2;
        CharacterMovement.Score = 11;
        Application.LoadLevel (CurrentLevel);

    }

    if ((CurrentLevel != 5) && (CharacterMovement.Lives == 0)) { // Change this
        isLost = true;
        Debug.Log ("is now true");
        CurrentLevel = 5;
        Debug.Log ("current level is set to 5");
        Application.LoadLevel (CurrentLevel);
    }

    if (CurrentLevel == 5) {
        Debug.Log ("this is level 5");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab)) {
            Debug.Log ("tab is pressed");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy.